# "Жареные факты"

Tags: фразеология

Откуда пошло выражение "жареные факты"? Я еще понимаю "горячие" в значении "сенсационные", но почему - "жареные"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я так понимаю, что они приготовленные, не натуральные.
А вообще выражение не очень давнего времени. Не знаю, встречалось ли оно до 70-х, а то и 80-х годов прошлого века. Потом кто-то (не Горбачев ли?) пустил в оборот. Так что искать серьёзную этимологию не приходится.

Answer (score 0):

С пылу, с жару потому что. Наисвежайшие, только что приключившиеся, только что приготовленные судьбой.

Comment: Вряд ли. Смысл другой. Жареные факты - это сомнительного качества как раз.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?